# Python html parsing using beautiful soup issues

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the name of all organizations from https://www.devex.com/organizations/search using beautifulsoup.However, I am getting an error. Can someone please help.

import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}

titles = []
pages = np.arange(1, 2, 1)

for page in pages:

page = requests.get("https://www.devex.com/organizations/search?page%5Bnumber%5D=" + str(page) + "", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
movie_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='info-container')

sleep(randint(2,10))

for container in movie_div:

```
    name = container.a.find('h3', class_= 'ng-binding').text
    titles.append(name)
```

movies = pd.DataFrame({
'movie': titles,

})

## to see your dataframe

print(movies)

## to see the datatypes of your columns

print(movies.dtypes)

## to see where you're missing data and how much data is missing

print(movies.isnull().sum())

## to move all your scraped data to a CSV file

movies.to_csv('movies.csv')

Comment: Mention what error you are getting along with the question

Answer (score 0):

you may try with something like

```python
name = bs.find("h3", {"class": "ng-binding"})
```